# How to merge inaccessible free space into main partition on Mac

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I recently installed linux on my Macbook Pro by partitioning my harddrive using Disk Utility. I've since decided to erase Linux and just go back to an unpartitioned Mac installation.

However, I somehow got things in a state where Disk Utility won't show me the partition I want to merge back into Mac.

If I run diskutil list in the terminal, this is what I see:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
                    (free space)                         43.0 GB    -
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         207.8 GB   disk0s2
```

And in Disk Utility, the free space is not shown as a partition I can hit the minus button[image: missing partition]

Is there any way for me to get back to just having a single partition in macOS on it, utilizing the full space of the drive? Preferably without having to erase the entire disc and reinstall macos from scratch (unless every other option isn't worth the effort.)